# [Fatal Error] :16164:240: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity

Tags: grails

I usually get this error in grails. I tried creating new grails project and while running the app, i get this problem and I have problem working with grails now. I deleted .grails and .groovy directory too. I use MacBookPro.
I tried clean too, but no luck.

Comment: I am using grails 2.3.0

Comment: I does not look like configuration version problem. You have a bad xml somewhere that you are reading.  It must be a code issue?

Comment: I noticed this when using domain abstract classes. Do you have any?

Comment: It went eventually. I mean after stopping and restarting couple of times.

Comment: I have the same problem. windows, grails 2.3.6. No solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

this might be the plugin that you installed lately ? have used i8ln plugin and used like

> @I18nEnum(prefix = "", postfix = "", shortName = false, defaultNameCase = DefaultNameCase.UNCHANGED)

instead of

> @I18nEnum(prefix = '', postfix = ', shortName = false, defaultNameCase = DefaultNameCase.UNCHANGED)

Please ,check that what you have installed recently and comment our or remove the plugin to see the exact source of the problem.